# jQuery flip plugin switch function fails on switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a piece of code where I have two buttons and when I press one button I want a div to flip on the y-axis and when I press the other button I want the same div to flip on the x-axis. this works just fine when I use the button for the y-axis even if the previous flip was on the x-axis. But when I want to switch from the y-axis to the x-axis I need to press the x button twice because the first time nothing happens.

**So desired behavior is:**

click y button flip the div on the y-axis.

click x button flip the div on the x-axis.

**current behavior is:**

click y button div flips on the y-axis.

click x button nothing happens 
click x button again div flips on the x-axis.

I have no idea what the problem is, this is the best i got so far. 
All help is appreciated.

```js
var ax = 'x';
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#card').flip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    axis: 'x'
  });
  $('#left').click(function() {
    if (ax != 'y') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'y'
      });
      $("#card").on('flip:change', function() {
        $('#card').flip('toggle');
      });
      ax = 'y';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
  $('#right').click(function() {
    if (ax != 'x') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'x'
      });
      $("#card").on('flip:change', function() {
        $('#card').flip('toggle');
      });
      ax = 'x';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<button id="left">y</button>
<button id="right">x</button>
<div id="card">
  <div class="front">Front content</div>
  <div class="back">Back content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var ax = 'x';
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#card').flip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    axis: 'x'
  });
  
  
  $("#card").on('flip:change', function() {
    $('#card').flip('toggle');
  });
  
  $('#left').click(function() {

    if (ax != 'y') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'y'
      });
      
      ax = 'y';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
  $('#right').click(function() {
    if (ax != 'x') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'x'
      });
      
      ax = 'x';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<button id="left">y</button>
<button id="right">x</button>
<div id="card">
  <div class="front">Front content</div>
  <div class="back">Back content</div>
</div>
```

You should keep the `flip:change` outside the click event.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: could you elaborate what you did to make it work?, and maybe explain what caused the error?

Comment: @FutureCake I added the comment, ` flip:change` function should be outside the click event.

Answer (score 2):

You over-complicated the problem. Here is a solution inspired by the [documentation](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/). All you have to do is to call `flip` to change the axis on click on he buttons, and to listen on `flip:change` event which is fired every time you call `flip` to change the orientation in order to actually flip it.

```js
// Configure it to be manually flipped
$("#card").flip({
  trigger: 'manual'
});

// Change the axis
$('#left').click(function() {
  $("#card").flip({
    axis: 'y'
  });
});

$('#right').click(function() {
  $("#card").flip({
    axis: 'x'
  });
});

// Toggle it on change
$("#card").on('flip:change', function() {
  $('#card').flip('toggle');
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<button id="left">y</button>
<button id="right">x</button>

<div id="card">
  <div class="front">Front content</div>
  <div class="back">Back content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You ended up binding the `flip:change` event multiple times with each click. That caused x to flip twice when clicked after Y was clicked twice. Hence it looks like nothing is happening.

You can see that happening when adding a `debugger;` at the start of `$('#right').click(function() {` and using the console to debug your code.

Anyway, adding the event binding ones only fixes it as that is all you need.

Removing all instance of `$("#card").on('flip:change', function() {` in your code and only adding it one time, fixes the problem.

In this example I added it at the bottom of your code.

```js
var ax = 'y';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#card').flip({
    trigger: 'manual',
    axis: 'y'
  });
  $('#left').click(function() {
    //debugger;
    if (ax != 'y') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'y'
      });
      ax = 'y';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
  $('#right').click(function() {
    //debugger;
    if (ax != 'x') {
      $("#card").flip({
        axis: 'x'
      });
      ax = 'x';
    } else {
      $("#card").flip('toggle');
    }
  });
  // Only bind ones.
  $("#card").on('flip:change', function() {
    $('#card').flip('toggle');
  });
});
```

```css
#card {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<button id="left">y</button>
<button id="right">x</button>
<div id="card">
  <div class="front">Front content</div>
  <div class="back">Back content</div>
</div>
```